# How to create a MYSQL connection through a remote server?

Tags: mysql

I need to create a new connection to my remote server's mysql using mysql workbench. So I created a new user as follows and provided all the privillages.

```
CREATE USER 'user_99'@'10.8.204.211' IDENTIFIED BY 'Changeme5_123';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'user_99'@'10.8.204.211';
```

Now I tried to create a new connection using mySQL workbench. But I am getting errors. Here I have attached how I tried that. Can some one help me to connect it?

[image]

Here are the errors.

[image]

Comment: What errors exactly? If you don't tell us the error it's hard for us to help you with it...

Comment: @ADyson I have updated the question. Sorry for that

Comment: So which of the suggested checks did you do?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Checked all. For 3, I have showed in my question as well. I gave all the privileges and added the password to the vault as well.

Comment: Is your IP address 10.8.204.211 or is that the ip of the server

Comment: 10.8.204.211 is my IP.But my remote server is on 10.62.161.35.I tried that one too by replacing it to the Hostname in mysql workbench.But the same error.@RiggsFolly

Comment: Ok, in the Setup dialog there, the ip address should be that ip of the server. I would suggest you may have to check that the firewall on the MySQL Server machine is not blocking you